# Create data frame and change variable each iteration in for loop or apply

Tags: r

i'm a bit new to R and this site has been an amazing help to me in answering a lot of questions. However, I’ve come across a recent problem and have exhausted all options to find a solution on my own and am in need of some help.

I am trying to write a code where I create multiple data frames (or matrices) **INSIDE** the loop and loop it 5000 times. On each loop I would like the variable to change so I can retrieve the data for each loop at a later point.
Also, I would like to be able to repeat this method for other data frames and in creating these new data frames, it draws upon other data frames based on the iteration it is on.
I have tried to find a solution to this and it seems that it could be either the `for loop` or `apply` function, but I am not sure as to how I could execute it. As an example of what I would like to see:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
df.a[i] <- data.frame (…information...)
df.b[i] <- data.frame (...information...)
df.c[i] <- data.frame (new.col.A=df.a[i]$column1, new.col.B=df.b[i]$column2)
}
```

Then, after having run the loop, if I were to write **df.c3** I would find the data frame created in the loop on the third iteration which has data from iteration 3 in **df.a** and **df.b**.

The ‘closest’ I have come to getting what I thought I needed was by doing this:

```
df.a = seq (1, 10, by=1)
df.b = seq (1,10, by=1)
df.c = seq (1,10, by=1)
for (i in 1:10) {
df.a[[i]] <- data.frame (...information)
...
}
```

But this typically results in an error of: **"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"**.

So i'm not sure what else i could do and really hope someone is able to help out.

Comment: `df.a` is a vector and you're indexing it as a list. It's also unclear what you want the outcome to be. A list of `data.frames`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create objects `df.x` as empty lists:

```
df.a <- list()
df.b <- list()
df.c <- list()
```

Then access (and write to) individual dataframes using double square backets:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  df.a[[i]] <- data.frame(...)
  df.b[[i]] <- data.frame(...)
  df.c[[i]] <- data.frame(new.col.A=df.a[[i]]$column1, new.col.B=df.b[[i]]$column2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i needed. However, an unexpected issue occurred that i didn't think to ask in my original post.

While the `for loop` works successfully for iterations of data frames (e.g. `df.a[[i]]`), i also need to iterate through the columns of one specific data frame (e.g. `df.rng`).

If the columns for df.rng are X1:X10, for example, on **iteration 4** (i.e. df.a[[4]]), i need it to also iterate through `df.rng$X[[4]]` (df.rng$X[[i]]) and so on.

Would you know how to do this? I will write a more detailed question if this is insufficient. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewJ use `df.rng[,i]`, if you have *only* this columns (X1,...,X10), in order, or `df.rng[,paste0("X",i)]` to reference the columns by name. Do *not* use `df.rng$X[[i]]`, as this means the value at row i and column "X" of `df.rng`.