# Create Data Frames by loop from List

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe

thanks in advance. Suppose I have multiple CSV files each containing rows and columns of a dataset, and each CSV has headers.  The row and column lengths differ across datasets:

"~/R/data_1.csv"
"~/R/data_2.csv"
     .
     .
     .
"~/R/data_n.csv"

I can read them all into a list of length `n` using `Sys.glob` and `lapply`.  Each element contains the row and column data for each data set:

```
dataFiles <- lapply(Sys.glob("~/R/data_*.csv"),read.csv)
```

But now I want to write another loop that takes the newly created `dataFiles` list and generates a data frame for each element between `1` and `n` that contains the row and columns.  Something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataFiles)){
df_[[i]] <- data.frame(dataFiles[[i]]
}
```

My result should be `n` data frames each containing the row and columns for each element in the list dataFiles.  I've tried reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500434/create-data-frame-and-change-variable-each-iteration-in-for-loop-or-apply) to replicate their work, but somehow end up creating more lists instead of data frames.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you want?  It seems like `dataFiles` already contains "n data frames each containing the row and columns for each" csv.  If you just want one data.frame, you can try: `taRifx::stack.list(dataFiles)`.

Comment: 'dataFiles' is one object that contains all the data from my data sets within 'n' separate elements. I want to extract 'n' objects each being a data frame from that list.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create `n` different variables in your environment. Generally it's much better to have them in a list to begin with. Why do you need a bunch of data.frame variables lying around. You can get to each from `dataFiles[[1]] ... dataFiles[[n]]` If you like you can give the elements of `dataFiles` `names()` so you can do `dataFiles$results` or something.

Comment: Well, I thought if I had each in a separate data frame, it will be easier to achieve my main goal: writing a loop that runs a non-linear least squares regression on each data frame.

Comment: It will be way harder if they are not in a list.  You don't even need a loop: use `lapply` to run your regression function on each element on the list.

Comment: Ah yeah I can see that.  Alright thanks guys, appreciate the insight I hope I didn't cause too many eye rolls lol.